# Overriding property in Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, overriding

I have a class like below

```
 class MainVC: UIViewController {

   lazy var someBtn: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.isHidden = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPressBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
   }()
 }
```

And I subclass MainVC and when I try to override someBtn, error message show as `Getter for 'someBtn' with Objective-C selector 'someBtn' conflicts with getter for 'someBtn' from superclass 'MainVC' with the same Objective-C selector`

```
class SecondVC: MainVC {
   override var someBtn:UIButton = {
      return UIButton()
   }
}
```

Comment: `override var someBtn...`. You forgot `var`.

Comment: The code you posted gives a completely different error.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a little change:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {
    lazy var someBtn: UIButton = createB()
    
    func createB() -> UIButton{
         let button = UIButton(type: .system)
         button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         button.isHidden = true
         return button
    }
}

class SecondVC: MainVC{
    override func createB() -> UIButton {
        return UIButton()
    }
}
```

turn `property` into `method`